# What bcp format file that I'm gonna used to insert 59 columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert, bcp

First Observation, limitation with this BCP format file
Data File: (Continuous up to three lines)

```
1;a;b;c;d;e;f;; 2;d;e;f;g;h;i;; 3;g;h;i;j;k;l;; 
4;j;k;l;m;n;o;; 5;m;n;o;p;q;r;; 
6;p;q;r;s;t;u;;What bcp format file that I'm gonna used to insert 59 columns?
```

Format File:

```
9.0
9
1  SQLCHAR 0 0 "" 0 x ""
2  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 2  col1  Latin1_General_CI_AS
3  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 3  col2  Latin1_General_CI_AS
4  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 4  col3  Latin1_General_CI_AS
5  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 5  col4  Latin1_General_CI_AS
6  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 6  col5  Latin1_General_CI_AS
7  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 7  col6  Latin1_General_CI_AS
8  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 8  col7  Latin1_General_CI_AS
9  SQLCHAR 0 0 "" 0 x ""
```

Table structure

```
Create Table bcp2 (id bigint identity(1,1), col1 varchar(2), col2 varchar(2), col3 varchar(2), col4 varchar(2), col5 varchar(2), col6 varchar(2), col7 varchar(2), dte bit default 0)
```

When I try to add a another row, it gives this error message,

Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

If I arrange the data like this, it gives an error message,
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

This arrangement (three continuous lines) gives an error,

```
1;a;b;c;d;e;f;; 2;d;e;f;g;h;i;; 3;g;h;i;j;k;l;; 
4;j;k;l;m;n;o;; 5;m;n;o;p;q;r;; 
6;p;q;r;s;t;u;;
```

This arrangement (one line) does not give error, it will insert all 6 rows,

```
1;a;b;c;d;e;f;; 2;d;e;f;g;h;i;; 3;g;h;i;j;k;l;; 4;j;k;l;m;n;o;; 5;m;n;o;p;q;r;; 6;p;q;r;s;t;u;;
```

Second observation, This arrangement of data applies to specific format file

Data file and its arrangement:

```
1;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;; 2;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;; 3;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;; 
4;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;; 5;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;; 
6;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;;
```

... it inserts three rows

```
1;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;; 2;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;; 3;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;; 4;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;; 5;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;; 6;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;;
```

... it insert just one row

with this kind of format file:

```
9.0
12
1  SQLCHAR 0 0 "" 0 x ""
2  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 2  col1  Latin1_General_CI_AS
3  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 3  col2  Latin1_General_CI_AS
4  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 4  col3  Latin1_General_CI_AS
5  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 5  col4  Latin1_General_CI_AS
6  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 6  col5  Latin1_General_CI_AS
7  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 7  col6  Latin1_General_CI_AS
8  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 8  col7  Latin1_General_CI_AS
9  SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 9  col8  Latin1_General_CI_AS
10 SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 10 col9  Latin1_General_CI_AS
11 SQLCHAR 0 0 ";" 11 col10 Latin1_General_CI_AS
12 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\r\n" 0 x ""
```

Table structure remains the same,

```
Create Table bcp (id bigint identity(1,1), col1 varchar(2), col2 varchar(2), col3 varchar(2), col4 varchar(2), col5 varchar(2), col6 varchar(2), col7 varchar(2), col8 varchar(2), col9 varchar(2), col10 varchar(2), dte bit default 0)
```

Now, my question, what format file that I'm gonna use to get all data from all 59 columns to be inserted properly?

My actual data (part of it):

```
087728127;V1.10;R;WithMedia;58-1231925646@208.74.75.250;0002;Wed Jan 14 09:34:06 2009;NA;Wed Jan 14 09:35:06 2009;0;Origination CANCEL; 487;O;000054;SIP;0067*116;116.93.51.23;01149614244656;208.74.75.250;5372a7cc31a45f9a237780a125ce14ca@116.93.51.23;116.93.51.23;14840;208.74.75.250;12348;G.711u_64k,G.711a_64k,RFC 2833;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;050500;SIP;3072151001;208.74.75.250;49614244656;208.80.156.52;58-1-1231925646@208.74.75.250;0.0.0.0;0;208.74.75.250;12350;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;F;01149614244656;0;60;0;0;0000003A 496DB18E 484B6AB4 FA4B4AD0;;
087728128;V1.10;R;WithMedia;62-1231925689@208.74.75.250;0002;Wed Jan 14 09:34:49 2009;NA;Wed Jan 14 09:35:12 2009;0;Origination CANCEL; 487;O;050450;SIP;6326378682;116.93.51.98;011420556844118;208.74.75.250;call-00EC569B-CFE0-DD11-0216-4B6@116.93.51.98;116.93.51.98;11096;208.74.75.250;12364;G.729,RFC 2833;437;799;13988;25568;0;0;0;050001;SIP;6326378682;208.74.75.250;011420556844118;204.9.203.210;62-1-1231925689@208.74.75.250;204.9.203.210;11092;208.74.75.250;12366;G.729,RFC 2833;799;437;25568;13988;0;0;0;F;011420556844118;0;7;16;0;0000003E 496DB1B9 44AC3D38 FA4B4AD0;;
```

... the data is continuous and only separated by spaces after the double semicolon.

This is my actual format file:

```
9.0
61
1       SQLCHAR       0        0      ""         0     x                                      ""
2       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        2     Sequence                               Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        3     Version                                Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        4     RecordType                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        5     ConnectionType                         Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        6     SessionID                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        7     ReleaseCause                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        8     StartTime                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        9     AnswerTime                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        10    ReleaseTOD                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        11    WestofGMT                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        12    RelCauseTxt                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        13    RelCauseBin                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        14    1strelease                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        15    OrgTrunkId                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        16    OrgProtocol                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        17    OrgSrcNo                               Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        18    OrgSrcHost                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        19    OrgDestNo                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        20    OrgDestHost                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        21    OrgCallID                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        22    OrgRemPayIPAdd                         Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        23    OrgRemPayUDPAdd                        Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
24      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        24    OrgLocPayIPAdd                         Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
25      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        25    OrgLocPayUDPAdd                        Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
26      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        26    OrgCodecList                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
27      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        27    OrgIngrPck                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
28      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        28    OrgEgrPck                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
29      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        29    OrgIngrOct                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
30      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        30    OrgEgrOct                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
31      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        31    OrgIngrPckLoss                         Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
32      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        32    OrgIngrDelay                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
33      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        33    OrgIngrPckJitter                       Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
34      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        34    TermTrunkId                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
35      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        35    TermProtocol                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
36      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        36    TermSrcNo                              Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
37      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        37    TermSrcHost                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
38      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        38    TermDestNo                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
39      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        39    TermDestHost                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
40      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        40    TermCallID                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
41      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        41    TermRemPayIPAdd                        Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
42      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        42    TermRemPayUDPAdd                       Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
43      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        43    TermLocPayIPAdd                        Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
44      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        44    TermLocPayUDPAdd                       Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
45      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        45    TermCodecList                          Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
46      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        46    TermIngrPck                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
47      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        47    TermEgrPck                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
48      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        48    TermIngrOct                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
49      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        49    TermEgrOct                             Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
50      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        50    TermIngrPckLoss                        Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
51      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        51    TermIngrDelay                          Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
52      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        52    TermIngrPckJitter                      Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
53      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        53    FinRouteInd                            Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
54      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        54    RoutingDigits                          Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
55      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        55    CallDuration                           Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
56      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        56    PostDialDelay                          Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
57      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        57    RingTime                               Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
58      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        58    Duration                               Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
59      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        59    ConfID                                 Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
60      SQLCHAR       0        0      ";"        60    RPIDANI                                Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
61      SQLCHAR       0        0      ""          0    x                                      ""
```

This is my actual table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SansayRawInfo](
    [RawDataId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Version] [varchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RecordType] [varchar](44) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ConnectionType] [varchar](26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [SessionID] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ReleaseCause] [varchar](14) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [StartTime] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [AnswerTime] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ReleaseTOD] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [WestofGMT] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RelCauseTxt] [varchar](42) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RelCauseBin] [varchar](28) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [1strelease] [varchar](22) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgTrunkId] [varchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgProtocol] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgSrcNo] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgSrcHost] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgDestNo] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgDestHost] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgCallID] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgRemPayIPAdd] [varchar](26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgRemPayUDPAdd] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgLocPayIPAdd] [varchar](26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgLocPayUDPAdd] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgCodecList] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgIngrPck] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgEgrPck] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgIngrOct] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgEgrOct] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgIngrPckLoss] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgIngrDelay] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrgIngrPckJitter] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermTrunkId] [varchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermProtocol] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermSrcNo] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermSrcHost] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermDestNo] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermDestHost] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermCallID] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermRemPayIPAdd] [varchar](26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermRemPayUDPAdd] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermLocPayIPAdd] [varchar](26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermLocPayUDPAdd] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermCodecList] [varchar](138) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermIngrPck] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermEgrPck] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermIngrOct] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermEgrOct] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermIngrPckLoss] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermIngrDelay] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TermIngrPckJitter] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [FinRouteInd] [varchar](44) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RoutingDigits] [varchar](74) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CallDuration] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [PostDialDelay] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RingTime] [varchar](16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Duration] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ConfID] [varchar](46) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RPIDANI] [varchar](74) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good detail, but you are missing the *actual bcp command* that you are using.
I suspect a problem with the **-c -r and -t** options.

In any case, some things to try:

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/67409)

- Check your line termination options.
- Hidden characters in the data file.
- Using spaces for delimiters in a data file.